# Use flexbox to wrap elements within flex elements to the next line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox which contains "product boxes", which themselves contain thumbnails of the product. Is there a way I can wrap the thumbnails to the next line if the product box runs out of space on that line? I might have 10+ thumbnails per product so it might even need to run to the next *two* lines if needed, but they should still be "inline" with the reset of the products and not line-break at their beginning and end.

I don't have to use flexboxes, but I assume they might be useful for something like this. However I cannot figure this one out. Thanks!

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  background: yellow;
}

.product {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1em;
  background: magenta;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What happens:

[image]

What I would like to happen:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is impossible with flexbox. I could probably just make everything `display: inline;`.

Comment: If you drop the `product` wrapper you can make it work...and use `nth-child` to create a _gap_ after every 3rd item

Comment: Was considering that (although the number of thumbnails per product is arbitrary), but I would like to give the product div a nice background, or even make it clickable with an <a> link or Javascript, so having the logical HTML hierarchy would be nice to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few smaller adjustments you can achieve that, where to not group the thumbnails and use a wrapper to compensate for the top margin.

```css
.products {
  background: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;          /*  avoid collapsed margin on parent element  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -15px;             /*  so margin only affect second row  */
}

.products a {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: magenta;
}

.products a:nth-child(3n) {      /*  target every 3rd element with a right margin  */
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">1</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">2</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">3</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">4</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">5</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">6</div></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As you mentioned in a comment, where the amount of thumbnails is arbitrary, it might not be practical to use `nth-child` to create the gap between the elements to be viewed as a group.

Based on that fact, and assumed you generate these thumbnails dynamically, you can either use a space element, or like below, add the margin inline.

```css
.products {
  background: yellow;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;          /*  avoid collapsed margin on parent element  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -15px;             /*  so margin only affect second row  */
}

.products a {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: magenta;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">1</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">2</div></a>
    <a style="margin-right: 15px" href="#"><div class="thumbnail">3</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">4</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="thumbnail">5</div></a>
    <a style="margin-right: 15px" href="#"><div class="thumbnail">6</div></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A space element as you mentioned is probably best my purposes. Thanks, this is a bit cleaner than the other answer so I'll accept this one. I was not aware of `inline-flex`, but it looks like it's exactly what I wanted originally!

Answer (score 2):

- Removed the two `.product`
- then wrapped each thumbnail in an `inline-block`
- the `inline-blocks` have a -2.5px left and right margins so they appear to belong to the same container when inline.
- the outer block is `display:table`
- every 3rd thumbnail has a .5em right margin (as suggested by LGSon)

### Demo

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

main {
  display: table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  padding: .5em;
  background: yellow;
}

b {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 10px -2.5px;
  background: magenta
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

main>div>b:nth-of-type(3n) {
  margin-right: .5em
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="products">

    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>
    <b><div class="thumbnail"></div></b>

  </div>
</main>
```